# Searching in man pages

Tags: search, man

Recently, I stumbled over some configuration files. To gather more information about its structure and how the its used, I either do a quick research on the internet (just ask Google) or use the man command directly in the terminal.

In most cases it is obvious by which application the configuration belongs to which configuration file. The man page of the application refers to other man pages for further information and documentation. In the case I have no idea, a `man -k file-or-path` or `apropos file-or-path` points me sometimes in the right direction.

This approach works in most cases, but not always. Is there a convenient way to get more information in cases where I have no clue (apart from a research on the internet)? What are other strategies? Are there tools (some kind of ZSH plugins) you may recommend?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Search for a string in all man pages?

Comment: Once you get to that level of directedness in response to that level of vague input you're really talking about a search engine. Also, man pages are only installed if you install the corresponding package. I'd say google is actually the only reasonable solution here.

Comment: What about `man -K file-or-path`?

Comment: Consider `apropos` (latin, I think for "appropriate"). As above, I believe that `man -k` is roughly identical to `apropos`.

Comment: `man -K` (please note the capitalized "K" in contrast to my example above) file-or-path is kind of what I was searching for. Thanks @CristianCiupitu!

Comment: @ericx According to the Oxford English Dictionary, *apropos* is actually an English word with the meaning "with reference to", "concerning" (it can also mean appropriate). It's derived from French *à propos* - (with regard) to (this) purpose. The latin version of this is *ad propositum*.